# grails tutorial not finding right view page

Tags: grails

I followed the grails tutorial at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#creatingAnApplication which works ok.

But when I click the link helloworld.HelloController i get a 404 page with

HTTP Status 404 - /helloworld/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/hello/index.jsp at the top.

I haven't changed anything since installation. I am on Mac Mavericks (10.9)

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Do you have any files under your project's views? Did you run generate-all *? (just an example). Do you have an index-action in your HelloController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've missed to change controller, it have look like this:

```
class HelloController {

    def index() {
        render "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it is exactly this. Thanks. I can't believe I missed it.